# Dash - Callback taking multiple inputs where some may or may not exist depending on radio-item selection

Tags: plotly-dash

Let's say there is a radio-button with two options: ‘Default value’ and ‘Manual selection.’ By default, ‘Default value’ is selected. Radio-item selection provides either a dropdown or an input box respectively. Additionally, there is a button called ‘Submit’ which performs an action when clicked taking in the input value from the 'Default value' or 'Manual Selection.'

In this case, how to write a callback function to perform a task when the ‘Submit’ button is clicked? Inputs to this callback need to be the button click, and the values of dropdown or input box. When I provide all three values (button, dropdown, input box) as Input, I get the error of “A nonexistent object was used in an Input of a Dash callback” since either the input box or the dropdown is not present. If I group the inputs into two callback functions with (button + input box) as input and (button + dropdown) as input, I still get the same error. Any idea how to write a callback for this?

#### Update

Solved in plotly community by [José Luiz Ferreira](https://community.plotly.com/u/jlfsjunior). Here is the [link](https://community.plotly.com/t/callback-taking-multiple-inputs-where-some-may-or-may-not-exist-depending-on-radio-item-selection/58300/3).

Comment: Thanks for the shoutout!

Comment: @JoséLuizFerreira can you please upvote the question if you think it is useful?

Comment: Could you please add the solution? From the link, it is not too obvious. (I will upvote then! :D )